# Connection is closed mysqldatareader

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I dont know why my connection keeps closing while not having anything to close the connection. I have tried enclosing them in `using` block but to no avail. Is there a better way to pass a single select query into a `string`?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string username = txtUsername.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;
    string query = "SELECT isActive FROM tblUser WHERE username = ?username AND password = ?password";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con.connection);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?password", password);
    con.connection.Open();
    MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    string isActive="";
    string updatequery = "UPDATE tbluser SET DateLastLogin= '" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-mm-yy") + "',TimeLastLogin = '" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay + "', IsActive = 1 WHERE username = ?username";
    if (mdr.HasRows)
    {
        if(con.connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)con.connection.Open();
        while (mdr.Read())
        {
            isActive = mdr[0].ToString();
            if (isActive.Equals("1"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This user is already logged in!");
            }
            else
            {
                MySqlCommand updatecmd = new MySqlCommand(updatequery, con.connection);

                con.OpenConnection();
                updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", username);
                updatecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                pnlLogin.Hide();
                pnlMenu.Show();
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + username);

            }

        }

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid user credentials.");
    }



}
```

Comment: I don't know about `MySqlConnection`, but certainly with a `SqlConnection` you cannot use the connection for something else whilst a `DataReader` is open.  Have you tried using a second `Connection` object to do the Updates?

Comment: I didnt notice i was using only 1 connection for both commands. Thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed my code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a second connection statement for the Update query and removed other statements that opened the connection.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


                string username = txtUsername.Text;
                string password = txtPassword.Text;
                string query = "SELECT isActive FROM tblUser WHERE username = ?username AND password = ?password";

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con.connection);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", username);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?password", password);
                    con.connection.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    string isActive="";
                    string updatequery = "UPDATE tbluser SET DateLastLogin= '" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-mm-yy") + "',TimeLastLogin = '" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay + "', IsActive = 1 WHERE username = ?username";
                    if (mdr.HasRows)
                    {

                        while (mdr.Read())
                        {
                            isActive = mdr[0].ToString();
                            if (isActive.Equals("1"))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("This user is already logged in!");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MySqlCommand updatecmd = new MySqlCommand(updatequery, con.connection2);

                                con.connection2.Open();
                                    updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", username);
                                    updatecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    pnlLogin.Hide();
                                    pnlMenu.Show();
                                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + username);

                            }

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid user credentials.");
                    }

                    con.CloseConnection();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not closing your connection (which is wrong) you don't need to verify whether your con is closed to open it, so you need to remove this:

```
if(con.connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)con.connection.Open();`
```

Additionally you don't need to open your connection again, I believe is closing your connection because you are reopening it with `con.OpenConnection();` when your `!isActive.Equals("0")`. Try deleting `con.OpenConnection();` and check it.

If you don't have any new queries on the lines following after this code you provided is better to `.Close()` your connection.

Comment: I only added that because it kept saying it was closed. And also removed the con.CloseConnectiont() to see if it would still create the error. My problem was actually i was using 1 connection to execute both queries as Jonathan Willock pointed out